# Rails 7 and Stimulus: How to integrated TailwindCSS without any other JS library?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, tailwind-css, alpine.js, stimulusjs

For my new hobby project, I wanted to use Rails 7, Stimulus and the TailwindCSS framework. I was looking for some TailwindCSS templates and I found out that basically all of the templates require some other JS framework to work properly - typically React, Vue, or Alpine.

So basically, if I planned to use Rails 7 with Stimulus, I apparently also need to use, say, Alpine, because Tailwind does not come with templates on Stimulus. Similar situation is for Bootstrap.

Am I overlooking something, or is it common today that a Rails app is using its "native" JS framework (Stimulus) and another framework (React, Alpine) for the interaction with a CSS framework? Or - is there a better/cleaner way to handle this?

A few years back, the typical setup was Rails + JS/jQuery and integrating CSS templates was quite straightforward :)

Comment: Using TailwindCSS successfully without any of those frameworks.

Comment: @dbugger Also with components?

Comment: No -- but that's likely where the framework comes in. Might want to explicitly add that to your question